# Invalid length parameter passed to the SUBSTRING function behavior when called from a job

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
DECLARE @STSDF VARCHAR(MAX)
(@STSDF will eventually receive an html page, that i stripped, it's not important)
DECLARE @TEST INT
SET @TEST= LEN(@STSDF)
```

RESULT IS 2243

When I manually run my stored procedure

`SET @STSDF = LEFT(@STSDF,2243)` --working fine

`SET @STSDF = LEFT(@STSDF,@TEST)` --working fine

When i call my procedure from a job

`SET @STSDF = LEFT(@STSDF,2243)` --working fine

`SET @STSDF = LEFT(@STSDF,@TEST)` --i get the following error

> Executed as user: xxxx. Invalid length parameter passed to the
>   SUBSTRING function. [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 536)  The statement has
>   been terminated. [SQLSTATE 01000] (Error 3621).  The step failed.

Why isn't it working when i call it from a job ?!?

**SQL:**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_CheckScheduleTEST] 
AS 
DECLARE @url VARCHAR(MAX) 
DECLARE @win INT 
DECLARE @hr  INT 
DECLARE @intTest INT 

select @url = 'lbcrq.qc.ca/Stat17/HoE_PeARive-Nord_Caps.htm'; 

EXEC @hr = sp_OACreate 'WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1', @win OUT 

EXEC @hr = sp_OAMethod @win, 'Open', NULL, 'GET', @url, 'false' 

EXEC @hr = sp_OAMethod @win, 'Send' 

CREATE TABLE #TT(txtValue NVARCHAR(MAX)) 
    INSERT INTO #TT EXEC sp_OAGetProperty @win, 'ResponseText' 

DECLARE @STSDF VARCHAR(MAX) 
SET @STSDF = (SELECT txtValue FROM #TT) 

SET @STSDF = dbo.udf_StripHTML2(@STSDF) 
SET @intTest = LEN(@STSDF) - 202 
SET @STSDF = LEFT(@STSDF,@intTest)
```

Comment: The error relates to a `SUBSTRING` call, your example uses `LEFT` ... its not the guilty code

Comment: Using The LEFT function, the error i get is "Invalid length parameter passed to the SUBSTRING function"

N.B. if i replace LEFT(@STSDF,@TEST) by SUBSTRING(@STSDF,1,@TEST) i get the same error

When i comment that particular line, it works, it is the guilty code

Comment: is this all of your code... i'm suspecting not :)

Comment: Do you mean you see *"Invalid length parameter passed to the **LEFT** function"* ? If you see it talking about SUBSTRING when you use LEFT you are not running what you think or the issue is elsewhere.

Comment: Please post the entire procedure...

Comment: When i comment the line
SET @STSDF = LEFT(@STSDF,@TEST) i do not get the error "Invalid length parameter passed to the SUBSTRING function"

Comment: Post the entire procedure...

Comment: What do you get if you run this query:   `SELECT LEFT('abc',-1)`

Comment: i get Msg 536, Level 16, State 1, Line 40
Invalid length parameter passed to the left function.

Comment: it works, but if you call that procedure from a job, it returns :
Message
Executed as user: xxxxxx. Invalid length parameter passed to the SUBSTRING function. [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 536).  The step failed.

Comment: When you are manually running it and it is succeeding, are you exposing it to exactly the same data as when the job runs? The issue, as I am sure you have figured out from the error, is that the value for @intTest is not valid, and throws the error.

Comment: 1- Create the procedure sp_CheckScheduleTEST
2- Execute it, it works
3- Call the procedure from a job `code` Execute sp_CheckScheduleTEST
4- Get the error in job history

Comment: Doesn't seem my first thought is the issue then. Does the user running the job have a long username? Can you try running the job as another user on your test system to see if it has a bearing? The issue is somewhere in the job settings, I am now thinking.

Comment: Same result with my own user executing the SQL Agent Service

Comment: `@STSDF` is not what you expect.  Create a new table with a varchar() column and insert the values you acquire through the run of your code, look and check that they are what you expect.  You should examine the @hr returns code to ensure the operation succeeded.

Comment: Why are you subtracting 202 from the length? What if the length gives a number under 202, then you get a negative computed length...

Comment: @Alex K. you're close
- When i get the value from the temp table, i get the error
- When i manually set the value with the **exact same string**, it works ?!?!

Comment: If you log all the data you will see exactly why

Comment: @bastos.sergio Surprisingly, it works if i remove the -202 ?!?!
`code`
SET @intTest = LEN(@STSDF) - 202
SELECT @intTest **(Result is 2243 and it's not working)**
SET @intTest = LEN(@STSDF) 
SELECT @intTest **(Result is 2245 and it's working)**

Answer (score 1):

"Invalid length parameter passed to the " ***only*** happens when you pass something other than a positive integer as the final parameter (second for LEFT, third for SUBSTRING).

To identify why you're getting this error while using your stored proc: simply comment out the line that's causing the error and, instead have the proc return the value that's being passed to the LEFT function. This will help you figure out why a bad value is getting passed...

Comment: If it was a positive integer problem, it would not work when i execute it manually with the exact same values

Comment: If it weren't a positive int problem then the query would run without error regardless of how you ran it (manually or via a proc). I STRONGLY suggest doing what I mentioned and temporarily re-write your proc to display the values that's being passed to the LEFT function.

Answer (score 0):

First, as stated by Alan the error only happens when you pass something other than a positive integer in the second parameter in the `LEN` function...

Consider the following example:

```
DECLARE @TestString As Varchar(max)
SET @TestString = '  123456789      '
SELECT LEFT(@TestString, 0) -- Returns ''
SELECT LEFT(@TestString, 5) -- Returns '  123'
SELECT LEFT(@TestString, 99999) -- Returns '  123456789      '
SELECT LEFT(@TestString, -1) -- Generates the error 'Invalid length parameter passed to the SUBSTRING function.'
```

Second, according to the `LEN` [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/len-transact-sql), the function returns a `BIGINT` number for `VARCHAR(MAX)` inputs **and** the LEN `function` ignores trailing spaces in the input...

So, you should be expecting a `BIGINT` number from the LEN output (not a `INT`), and also you need to validate whether or not trailing spaces should be considered as part of the length.

Again, consider this example:

```
DECLARE @TestString As Varchar(max)
SET @TestString = '  123456789      '
SELECT LEN(@TestString), DATALENGTH(@TestString)
-- Returns 11 for LEN, but 17 for DATALENGTH
```